# Install using pip a development version of a python package but with stable dependencies

Tags: python, pip

#### Background

The `pip install` command installs by default the newest stable version of a python package (stable versions as specified by [PEP426](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0426/))

The flag `--pre` for the `pip install` command tells pip also consider release candidates and develompent versions of python packages. As far as I understand, though, `pip install --pre packageA` it will install a dev version of `packageA`, but also dev version of all its dependencies.

#### The question is:

**Is it possible to use pip to install a development version of a package but stable versions of all its dependencies?**

#### Attempted solutions

One thing I have tried is to install the stable version of the package (with stable dependencies), and then reinstall the dev version without dependencies:

`pip install packageA
pip install --pre --no-deps --upgrade --force-reinstall packageA`

The problem, though, is that if the development version of `packageA` adds a new dependency, it will not be installed.

I am missing anything? Thanks!

Comment: Write a `requirements.txt` with pinned version numbers. But make sure the fit the conditions for the dependencies.

Comment: But I do not want to pin versions of any package... I would like an automatizable way to install the newest version of `packageA` (stable or not, just as `--pre` would do) and the most recent __stable__ versions of its dependencies. I'm not aware of how you can apply those constraints in `requirements.txt` without manually changing version numbers any time something is updated...

Answer (score 1):

I write a script to do this(`pip_install_dev_and_stable_of_dependencies.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys


def get_installed_packages():
    with os.popen('pip freeze') as f:
        ss = f.read().strip().split('\n')
    return set(i.split('=')[0].strip().lower() for i in ss)


def install_pre_with_its_dependencies_stable(package):
    already_installed_packages = get_installed_packages()
    os.system('pip install --pre ' + package)
    dependencies = ' '.join(
        p for p in get_installed_packages()
        if p not in already_installed_packages | set([package])
    )
    os.system('pip uninstall -y ' + dependencies)
    os.system('pip install ' + dependencies)


def main():
    for p in sys.argv[1:]:
        install_pre_with_its_dependencies_stable(p)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Usage:

```
(venv)$ chmod +x pip_install_dev_and_stable_of_dependencies.py
(venv)$ ./pip_install_dev_and_stable_of_dependencies.py pandas
```

This script do the following things:

```sh
# Step 1. get the packages that already installed
pip freeze
# Step 2. install the dev version of packageA
pip install --pre packageA
# Step 3. pick out the dependencies (compare with Step 1)
pip freeze
# Step 4. uninstall all the dependencies of packageA
pip uninstall depend1 depend2 ...
# Step 5. install the stable version of dependencies
pip install depend1 depend2 ...
```

Comment: But then if the dev version of `packageA` adds a new dependency, a development version of this dependency will be installed, am I right? For example, if `packageA 0.1.1.dev1` adds numpy as a dependency, I want `packageA 0.1.1.dev1` and the last _stable_ version of numpy installed. I don't want a dev version of numpy, only of `packageA`...

Comment: `pip install --pre --no-deps packageA`

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

1. First install your package without dependencies: `pip install --pre --no-deps package`
2. Then run again without `--pre` to install stable dependencies: `pip install package`

Comment: Does the second step install the dependencies of the development version of `package` (i.e. the one that first step installed)? Or does it only consider the dependencies of the last stable version? Unfortunately I cannot easily test it right now.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following

`pip install --upgrade "package>=0.0.1.dev"`

This should install the a new `dev` release without installing pre-release dependencies for other packages.

Comment: But you need to specify the version of the package. Unless I'm missing something, you cannot use it to get the "most recent" development version of the package.

Comment: @mgab, you can `cat requirements.txt` and pipe that using `xargs` into `pip install --pre --no-deps {package_name}` then `pip install {package_name}`